# 3 random integers not comparing properly in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a game that contains 3 cards, the 1st card and the 2nd card are shown to the user, but the 3rd card is hidden. The 3rd card will only be revealed when the players clicks the deal button. To win, the 3rd card has to be in between the 1st and the 2nd card, if not then the user loses. My problem is that my program doesn't compare the 3rd card properly to the 1st and 2nd. Sometimes I win even if the 3rd card is for example 6 when the 1st card is 1 and the 2nd card is 4, and loses even when the 3rd card is in between the 1st and the 2nd. How do I fix this? Here is my sample code inside the def function below:
Note: the cards list are just images of cards with numbers on them

```
cards = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11]

card = random.randint(0, 10)
card_2 = random.randint(0, 10)
card_3 = random.randint(0, 10)


def deal():
    deal = btnDeal
    money = int(lblMoney['text'])
    bet = int(txtBet.get())
    cards = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11]
    card = random.randint(0, 10)
    card_2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    card_3 = random.randint(0, 10)
    lblCard.config(image=cards[random.randint(0, 10)])
    lblCard2.config(image=cards[random.randint(0, 10)])
    lblCard3.config(image=cards[random.randint(0, 10)])

    if deal:

        if (card_3 > card) and (card_3 < card_2) or (card_3 > card_2) and (card_3 < card):
            money += bet
            lblMoney.config(text=money)
            showinfo(message="You Win!")
        elif card == card_2:
            higher = btnHigher
            lower = btnLower
            if higher:
                if card_3 > card and card_3 > card_2:
                    showinfo(message="You Win")
                elif card_3 < card and card_3 < card_2:
                    showinfo(message="You Lose")
            elif lower:
                if card_3 < card and card_3 < card_2:
                    showinfo(message="You Win")
                elif card_3 > card and card_3 > card_2:
                    showinfo(message="You Lose")
        else:
            showinfo(message="You Lose")
```

Comment: You are picking two entirely separate sets of random cards - one being used to update the display, and one being used to determine whether you won.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what you told it to do. You wrote:

```
         if card_3 > card and card_3 > card_2:
                showinfo(message="You Win")
```

You wanted:

```
         if card_3 > card and card_3 < card_2:
                showinfo(message="You Win")
```

Comment: Python has cascaded conditions, so it's simpler to write this as `if card < card_3 < card_2:`